# How to define a label for a custom shared-lib step in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins scripted pipeline with custom steps defined in my shared-lib repo under vars dir.
How can I assign a label to a custom step that I wrote which will appear in the build console-log page?

just like: 'node', 'sh', 'bat', 'zip' that appear in console window each time these steps are activated.